# XCode/Cocoa Objective-C - A couple questions

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

Sorry for the stupid post, but I am new to Objective-C programming and Cocoa and have a couple of questions which I can't find the answers to, I'm hoping someone can enlighten me.

Firstly, in XCode, when using the Interface builder, when I want to create a new object I drag the object to my 'assets'. However I can't specify methods or anything without manually creating a new class file. Is there any point using the interface builder's 'object'?

The first app I built to test things with, I put most of the code in the AppDelegate class files. Research has shown me that the AppDelegate's purpose is simply handling application events like launching and closing. Was I wrong in putting the methods in this class? Does it make any difference?

Finally, if I have several class files created, each handling their own functionality with an interface built and linked to the classes, then what do I do with the 'main' file? It seems to me that the 'main' file and 'appdelegate' class files will be for the most case left as-is?

I hope that makes sense. Again i'm sorry for the silly-sounding questions but I can't find any answers.

Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Firstly, in XCode, when using the Interface builder, when I want to create a new object I drag the object to my 'assets'. However I can't specify methods or anything without manually creating a new class file.

Sure you can. Just set the class of the object using the inspector.

Note that you can only connect nib objects to an outlet or action. You can't specify any random methods, nor should you—the whole point of the `IBOutlet`, `IBOutletCollection`, and `IBAction` keywords is to declare in code that these properties/methods are used by a nib.

> Is there any point using the interface builder's 'object'?

Yes, but pretty rarely. Usually you create objects in code and connect outlets to them.

The application's delegate is one object you may want to create in the MainMenu or MainWindow nib, if you build your application that way (the iOS templates have changed away from it for some reason).

> The first app I built to test things with, I put most of the code in the AppDelegate class files. Research has shown me that the AppDelegate's purpose is simply handling application events like launching and closing. Was I wrong in putting the methods in this class?

Probably. The application's delegate generally should only handle business relating to the `NS`/`UIApplicationDelegate` protocol.

On the flip side, it's OK to make your root view controller the application's delegate, if it makes sense to do so (and the `NS`/`UIApplicationDelegate` implementation code is not too voluminous). The question you have to answer—and only you can answer it for your application—is whether you are making your root view controller the application's delegate or the application's delegate the root view controller. If in doubt, keep them separate.

> Does it make any difference?

Long-term, yes. It's very easy, especially in the class of the application's delegate, to create a [Big Ball of Mud](http://www.laputan.org/mud/) class—one without well-defined and clearly-delineated responsibilities. Take dynamite to such a class as soon as possible.

> Finally, if I have several class files created, each handling their own functionality with an interface built and linked to the classes, then what do I do with the 'main' file? It seems to me that the 'main' file and 'appdelegate' class files will be for the most case left as-is?

Yes. They're boiler-plate.

If you haven't written any code in the application's delegate (or have removed everything you had put there into new and better-delineated classes), such that all that's left are empty method bodies or none at all, you can safely remove the application's delegate. You can always create it again later if you change your mind.

Note that if you delete your application delegate class, you should also change the main.m file—or the MainMenu/MainWindow nib, if you have one—to not refer to it. Your application won't build if your `UIApplicationMain` call (or any other code) refers to a class that doesn't exist, and it will crash if your MainMenu/MainWindow nib (or any other nib) refers to a class that doesn't exist.

There is no shame in your application having a delegate if you need it to, but if you don't, removing it and the class you were using for it eliminates future temptation to stuff code there or use it to store [third-order globals](http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2011-03-18/application-delegate-singletons).

Answer (score 1):

1. The point of using objects in interface builder is to connect methods of the object to UI elements.
2. It partly depends on what your methods are doing, but for the most part the app delegate class is going to be left alone. It isn't an actual requirement (your program will work either way) but it is common practice because it generally creates more maintainable code. The app delegate should just handle the application events ( using other classes to do any complex logic or heavy lifting ).
3. The 'main' file will most likely not change. I can't think of any reason to do so, but I wouldn't rule it out for some advanced cases.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I only used the Object thing in IB once, when I wanted a separate object to have some UI bindings.

About the app delegate and main file, yes, you'll leave them as-is most of the time. But if you try to do something besides test apps you'll need to handle open events to, for example, connect to a server, ask the user for a review, increment some launch counter, etc... Those are just examples!

The main file I advise you to left it alone and use the object oriented tools provided. You should have a view controller hierarchy, isolate your views from the data, and use the view controller to comunicate between view and model. Read about [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) if you want more info on how your application should be organized.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. last question: what do you mean view controller hierarchy? and isolating views? thanks again

Comment: Hmm, almost there. Views are objects too you see. You can have a view controller like MyListViewController, then that view controller has a bunch of views, a tab bar, a tableview, a search bar, etc...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10090/discussion-between-cristian-and-fbernardo)